# Specifying the default template for root route

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have an app for `posts` and `tags`. At the moment they don't have any relations, just in independent state.

I want specify the default template to be `postsList` and I had in `router.js` :

```
Router.route('/', {name: 'postsList'});
```

But this screws up the routes for `tags`, so I changed `routes.js` to look as:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('posts');
        return Meteor.subscribe('tags');
    }
});

Router.route('/posts', {name: 'postsList'});

Router.route('/posts/:_id', {
    name: 'postPage',
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('comments', this.params._id);
    },
    data: function () {
        return Posts.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});

Router.route('/posts/:_id/edit', {
    name: 'postEdit',
    data: function () {
        return Posts.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});

Router.route('/submit', {name: 'postSubmit'});

// Tags Start

Router.route('/tags', {name: 'tagsList'});

Router.route('/tags/submit', {name: 'tagSubmit'});

Router.route('/tags/:_id', {
    name: 'tagPage',
    data: function () {
        return Tags.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});

Router.route('/tags/:_id/edit', {
    name: 'tagEdit',
    data: function () {
        return Tags.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});

// Tags End


// Authentication

var requireLogin = function () {
    if (!Meteor.user()) {
        if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
            this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
        } else {
            this.render('accessDenied');
        }
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: ['postSubmit', 'tagSubmit']});
```

As a result, when I access to root route of the app, it gives me error:

> Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url: "http://askar-blog.meteor.com/."

Any solution?

https://github.com/tenzan/blog

If you're familiar with Rails you can do in `routes.rb`:

```
root 'posts#index'
resources :posts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just redirect it to go to the appropriate route.

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.redirect('/posts');
});
```